# How do I access a particular worksheet in the active spreadsheet in google sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The documentation claims there is a `getSheetByName()` and a `getSheets()` but they don't seem to be available anymore...
See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet

e.g. I'd like to do:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var wks = sheet.getSheetByName('Test');
```

Comment: They both work fine. What makes you think they are not available?

Answer (score 0):

`getSheetByName()` and `getSheets()` are both [spreadSheet class methods](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet), not [sheet class methods](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet).

I'm afraid you made a consfusion between these two. Btw it seems quite obvious that you can't get a "sheet" from a "sheet" doesn't it ?

You could easily avoid such errors by making use of the integrated autocomplete feature in the script editor. Simply type a period (.) after the class (then use CONTROL SPACE shortcut) name and you'll get all the available methods for this class.